# Table - missing $

Tags: tables

What is wrong with this table please? There is an error that $ is missing.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\st}{$^\circ$}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[]{M}
\label{objekty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A&  B $\alpha_{\mathrm{J2000}}$&    C $\delta_{\mathrm{J2000}}$&    D & E&  F\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
X   &$18^{\mathrm{h}}04^{\mathrm{m}}15,1^{\mathrm{s}}$& $+67\st 54^{\prime} 12,2^{\prime \prime}$&  0,209939&   V&  60\\

\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\\ Z
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use `54'` and `2''` no need for  `2^{\prime\prime}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `\st` sets its contents in math mode (because you want it to be a superscript `\circ`. However, in your `tabular`, you're using it in the following way:

```
$+67\st 54^{\prime} 12,2^{\prime \prime}$
```

This effectively expands to

```
$+67$^\circ$ 54^{\prime} 12,2^{\prime \prime}$
```

which tries to set a superscript (and `\circ`) outside of math mode, leading to the error. You could be interested in the following definition for `\st`:

```
\newcommand{\st}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much